# Connect to github through proxy

Tags: java, github, proxy

I want to connect (just connect, not do any operation, not for now) to github (with org.eclipse.egit.github) through a proxy in Java, I tried :

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", IP);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Port);
```

where IP and Port are Strings.

It don't seem to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a Preferences panel for configuring proxies under `Preferences…/General/Network Connections`

Comment: I think you didn't understand... I want to do that programatically, using the Github API in the eclipse egit packagr